# Is there anywhere to ask less scholastic questions on-line

Tags: discussion

Do any sites, forums etc., help with less scholastic based questions which are, broadly speaking, philosophical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can ask at https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/fallible-ideas/info